# Eclipse Lombok install Java16

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I want to install Lombok 1.18.20 in Eclipse jee-2021-03. I downloaded lombok jar and installed eclipse folder. When ı tried to open class i got this error. I looked Help-> About Eclipse IDE Lombok didnt add there. How can i solve this?

EDİT: I added `--illegal-access=permit` eclipse.ini file and its solved.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.19.0.I20210303-1800
java.version=16.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


org.eclipse.jdt.core
Error
Wed Jun 09 03:17:25 TRT 2021
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'northwind'.

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @75ad30c1
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.overrideLoadResult(ModuleClassLoader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:11687)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12880)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13061)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:11448)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```